# Not more than two colors of the same color

Tags: java

I call a method to get random colors to eight objects. If the color is the same for three objects in a row, then it's not valid. Only one or two colors besides each other of the same color is valid. I thought my code should work, but I still get three objects in a row of eight with the sam color! What have I done wrong? perhaps it could be done in a better and simplier way? Proposals are welcome!

Part of the loop to get eight random numbers

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // 8 objects in each column

// Call method to get random color
int color = getRandomColor(j);
```

The Method

```
public int getRandomColor(int j) {

    int color = randomNumber1.nextInt(8);

    colors[j] = color;
    if(j>1 && colors[j-1] == color && colors[j-2] == color) {
        getRandomColor(j);
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: You need `while`, not `if`. Also, you call `getRandomColor` again, but you're not doing anything with the result.

Comment: I used WHILE, but then the app closed down!

Comment: Closed down? Are you sure? It didn't simply go into an infinite loop?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Mr Lister, it shouldn't unless for some reason `randomNumber1.nextInt(8)` always returns the same color

Comment: Have you tried to use `SecureRandom` (without seed) to make sure that the random is truly random?

Comment: It's returning random number

Comment: @3D-kreativ are you sure every color is being added to `colors[]`?

Comment: @MrLister not quired Dave, the check is happening before returning a result with the same index `j`

Comment: Hmm, I have to test and try some more

Comment: @3D-kreativ some kind of stack would be a nice idea, or storing a single number and a count. Using recursion is always troublesome, using a loop construct instead should be preferred. And using `SecureRandom` instead of just any `Random` of course. Make sure you know how to use a debugger well.

Comment: Why not make an anwer then to show how you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int getRandomColor(int j){
  int color = randomNumber1.nextInt(8);
  colors[j] = color;

  while(j>1 && colors[j-1] == color && colors[j-2] == color){
    color = randomNumber1.nextInt(8);
    colors[j] = color;
  }
return color;
}
```